# can't access my site

Tags: site-url

I was trying to link up my new domain to my wordpress site but it went horribly wrong.

Im hosting my site on a AWS EC2 instance, i changed the URL in the settings on my wp-admin.

I have tried adding the lines to wp-config.php but yet that didnt fix it. 
I have tried going into my wp_options in MyPHPAdmin and changed the URL's back but thats not worked either. 
I have also tried editing the functions.php file and thats not working either :/

Help?

Comment: That seems impossible to me, if you already have taken all the actions. Have you tried reverting the domain to the old one? does it work this way?

Comment: Reverted it back to the original one but nothing :/ 

http://ec2-54-186-202-112.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Please enable the debug option in `wp-config.php`. There is an infinite redirect happening while accessing your website.

Comment: By the way, did you make any change to your `.htaccess` file? There might still be the old domain's redirection rules in that file.

Comment: Nothing in the .htcaccess file as ive even tried removing everything in the file and still the same response, just doing a backup of the content from my server and will enable the debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Once i enabled debug I found out the problem was infact that the function.php was in wp-include aswell as wp-admin.